# Obtener todos usuarios LDAP con java

Tags: java, ldap

Tengo el siguiente código y funciona:

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,  "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "Simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=" + user + ",cn=Users,dc=test,dc=com");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://93.5.95.5:389");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pass);

SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
NamingEnumeration objs = ctx.search("dc=test,dc=com",   "(objectClass=*)", searchControls);

while (objs.hasMoreElements())  {
    SearchResult match = (SearchResult) objs.nextElement();
    Attributes attrs = match.getAttributes();
    System.out.println(attrs.get("cn").toString());
    System.out.println("Found "+match.getName()+"-----"+ attrs);
}
```

Imaginemos que tenemos 4 usuarios: pepe1,pepe2,pepe3,pepe4, cuando hago login con pepe1 y pepe2, puedo hacer login pero con los otros 2 usuarios me da error

```
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]
```

Esperaba que cuando hago el while, encontrar una traza en el log de:

```
cn: pepe1
```

Me salen otros usuarios pero ni pepe1, pepe2,pepe3,pepe4. Lo raro es que si puedo hacer login con ese usuario

Comment: Ese error es debido a que en un momento te quiere hacer conexión a los usuarios pero algún campo entre el nombre del user y el pass están incorrectos. Si te hace login lo mas seguro es que tengas un user por defecto que se conecta sin problema al hacer login. ¿Usas weblogic en este caso o Tomcat?

Comment: uso WAS pero lo que me parece raro es en el quile no salga ningun usuario, tanto los q hacen login como los que no

Comment: ¿Y como lo tienes en tu web.xml? Igual tienes ahí mal puesta la configuración.

Comment: en este caso para probar, hago una conexion directa a LDAP, tengo un proyecto java y pruebo. En local tengo un OpenLDAP y puedo ver todo sin problemas pero en PRE hay un AD

Comment: No soy mucho de usar Websphere pero creo que en este caso igual tendrías que revisar wimconfig.xml o ldapsync.xml para ver si esta bien configurado, ya que el error señala a que o el user o pass no coinciden. Espero encontrar algo que te sirva de ayuda.